# How do I solve the error of relative namespaces in WSS4J

Tags: java, cxf, wss4j

I try to consume a Soap service with security using WSS4J 2.1.0 and CXF 2.7.5 technologies and I'm having an error with the relative namespaces in the canonicalization, how could I solve this? Is there another technology that solves this problem? . To the continuation I lay the trace of the exception. please if anyone could help me, thank you very much.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformException: org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element WS_Empresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: xmlns="Modernization_Consul"
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element WS_Empresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: xmlns="Modernization_Consul"
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.transform(DOMReference.java:531)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:343)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:474)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:359)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:556)
... 19 more
```